# Setting the value of an Android TextView when I click a button

Tags: java, android, textview, settext

In Java, if I want to set the value of a `JLabel` when I click a `JButton`, I can code it like this...

```
JButton button = new JButton("add");
JButton label = new JLabel();

public void addListenersToButtons(){
    button.addActionListener(this);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object src = e.getSource();
    if (src == button) {
        label.setText("this is the number = " + number);
    }
}
```

I want to be able to do a similar thing in Android, where I set the value of a `TextField` when the user clicks a button. What is the appropriate code for this in Android?

Comment: there have to be 10k examples on the internet...

Comment: must need to research about the problems for minimum 5-10 mins.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example:

```
    final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
            tv.setText("hellooo");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

```
button.setOnCLickListenere(new OnCLickListsner(){

public void onClick(View v){
 text.setText("text"); //assuming you have reference for the TextView and button
}
});
```

But you definitely need to go through the basics of android first..

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int num=0;
plus.setOnCLickListenere(new OnCLickListsner(){
public void onClick(View v){

num=num+1;
 text.setText("Number "+num); //assuming you have reference for the TextView and button
}
});

minus.setOnCLickListenere(new OnCLickListsner(){
public void onClick(View v){

num=num-1;
 text.setText("Number "+num); //assuming you have reference for the TextView and button
}
});
```

Hope you want to do something like this. Here are two buttons on pressing `plus` value will be added, and on pressing `minus` a number will be deducted.